# Kafka producer and consumer not working properly on python with docker

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka, kafka-python

Im working on a project that uses kafka producer and consumer in order to acquire articles (with specific topics) from a news_api every two hours and then with a consumer save them in a mongodb.

So i made three classes one for KafkaAdminClient one for KafkaProducer and one for KafkaConsumer.

The servers for my kafka are running on a docker container. The main application is a flask app, and thats where i start all the threads and the ones for kafka.

Ive been trying to change a lot of little things but it just seems very unstable and i dont know why. Firstly the data gets on the consumer and eventually in the mongodb at a random time. Then the old topics in the consumer dont get deleted and the database keeps getting populated with new and old values.

Now that i put a group in the consumer and i added the kafkaAdminClient class i dont get messages in the consumer at all. All i get is this:

```
articleretrieval-flask_api-1          | WARNING:kafka.cluster:Topic health is not available during auto-create initialization articleretrieval-flask_api-1          | WARNING:kafka.cluster:Topic business is not available during auto-create initialization articleretrieval-flask_api-1          | WARNING:kafka.cluster:Topic war is not available during auto-create initialization articleretrieval-flask_api-1         
 | WARNING:kafka.cluster:Topic motorsport is not available during auto-create initialization articleretrieval-flask_api-1          
| WARNING:kafka.cluster:Topic sources is not available during auto-create initialization articleretrieval-flask_api-1         
 | WARNING:kafka.cluster:Topic science is not available during auto-create initialization articleretrieval-flask_api-1         
 | WARNING:kafka.cluster:Topic technology is not available during auto-create initialization articleretrieval-flask_api-1         
 | WARNING:kafka.cluster:Topic education is not available during auto-create initialization articleretrieval-flask_api-1          
| WARNING:kafka.cluster:Topic space is not available during auto-create initialization articleretrieval-flask_api-1          
| INFO:kafka.consumer.subscription_state:Updated partition assignment: [] articleretrieval-flask_api-1    
| INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka:29092 <connected> [IPv4 ('172.19.0.4', 29092)]>: Closing connection.
```

kafkaConsumerThread.py:

```
class KafkaConsumerThread:
    def __init__(self, topics, db,logger):
        self.topics = topics
        self.db = db
        self.logger = logger

    def start(self):
        self.logger.debug("Getting the kafka consumer")
        try:
            consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=['kafka:29092'],
                                     auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                                    #  group_id='my_group',
                                     enable_auto_commit=False,
                                     value_deserializer=lambda x: json.loads(x.decode('utf-8')))
        except NoBrokersAvailable as err:
            self.logger.error("Unable to find a broker: {0}".format(err))
            time.sleep(1)
        consumer.subscribe(self.topics + ["sources"])

        for message in consumer:
            self.logger(message)
            if message.topic == "sources":
                self.db.insert_source_info(message.value["source_name"], message.value["source_info"])
            else:
                self.db.insert_article(message.topic, [message.value])
```

```
def on_send_success(record_metadata):
    return
    # print(record_metadata.topic)
    # print(record_metadata.partition)

def on_send_error(excp):
    print(excp)

def call_apis(self, topics, news_api, media_api):
    try:
        producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['kafka:29092'],
                                 max_block_ms=100000,
                                 value_serializer=lambda x: json.dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))
    except NoBrokersAvailable as err:
        # self.logger.error("Unable to find a broker: {0}".format(err))
        time.sleep(1)

    domains = []
    try:
        if producer:
            for topic in topics:
                articles = news_api.get_articles(topic)
                for article in articles:
                    if article['source'] != '':
                        if article['source'] not in domains:
                            domains.append(article['source'])

                        producer.send(topic, value=article).add_callback(on_send_success).add_errback(on_send_error)
                        producer.flush()
            for domain in domains:
                source_info = media_api.get_source_domain_info(domain)
                if source_info:
                    producer.send("sources", value={"source_name": domain, "source_info": source_info}).add_callback(on_send_success).add_errback(on_send_error)

                    # Flush the producer to ensure all messages are sent
                    producer.flush()
    except AttributeError:
        self.logger.error("Unable to send message. The producer does not exist.")



class KafkaProducerThread:
    def __init__(self, topics,logger):
        self.topics = topics
        self.news_api = NewsApi()
        self.media_api = MediaWikiApi()
        self.logger = logger

    def start(self):
        # Call the APIs immediately when the thread starts
        call_apis(self, self.topics, self.news_api, self.media_api)

        # Use a timer to schedule the next API call
        timer = Timer(7200, self.start)
        timer.start()
```

kafkaAdminClient.py:

```
class KafkaAdminThread:
    def __init__(self,topics):
        self.topics = topics

    def start(self):
        admin_client = KafkaAdminClient(
            bootstrap_servers=['kafka:29092'], 
                client_id='my_client'
        )
        topic_list = []
        for topic in self.topics:
            topic_list.append(NewTopic(name=topic, num_partitions=1, replication_factor=1))
        admin_client.create_topics(new_topics=topic_list, validate_only=False)
```

app.py:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Creating a new connection with mongo
    # threading.Thread(target=lambda: app.run(port=8080, host="0.0.0.0",debug=True,use_reloader=False)).start()
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
    producerThread = KafkaProducerThread(TOPICS,logging)
    adminThread = KafkaAdminThread(TOPICS)
    executor.submit(adminThread.start)
    flaskThread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: app.run(port=8080, host="0.0.0.0", debug=True, use_reloader=False))
    executor.submit(flaskThread.start())
    time.sleep(15)
    executor.submit(producerThread.start)
    consumerThread = KafkaConsumerThread(TOPICS, db,logging)
    executor.submit(consumerThread.start)
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"

  kafka:
    container_name: kafka_broker_1
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    links:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29092:29092"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:29092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://0.0.0.0:29092,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock%

  flask_api:
    build:
      context: . #Very important it refers where the root will be for the build.
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    links:
        - kafka
    environment:
      - FLASK-KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP-SERVERS=kafka:29092
      - SERVER_PORT=8080
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - kafka
```

Comment: Unrelated, but why aren't you using `FLASK-KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP-SERVERS` in your code? (also I think env vars cannot have hyphens)

Comment: Also, please create a [mcve]. If you're having AdminClient problems, you don't need to include producer/consumer code. Plus, we don't know what this `news_api` function does, so we cannot reproduce any producer problem

Comment: @OneCricketeer sorry for the code rush up, everything was just set up quick and with all the changes that I kept adding it got confusing. The news_api is tested and works fine. It basically returns articles with a source name and some content. Also adminClient was added afterwards so I'm guessing it's not even needed.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I wanted to ask. Is the consumer supposed to start inserting the messages as soon as producer sends them?

Comment: Consuming/reading, rather than "inserting", but yes, it should.

Answer (score 0):

> the old topics in the consumer dont get deleted

Nothing in your shown code is deleting topics. The only way they would be deleted is if the Kafka container restarted since you've not mounted a volume for Kafka or Zookeeper to persist them.

> and the database keeps getting populated with new and old values.

I assume your producer isn't keeping track of what sources it has read so far? If so, you'll end up with duplicates in the topic. I
suggest using `kafka-console-consumer` to debug whether the producer is actually working the way you want.
Likewise, you've disabled consumer auto commits, and I see no code committing manually, so when the consumer restarts, it'll re-process any existing data in the topics. Group / AdminClient settings shouldn't affect that, but setting a group will allow you to actually maintain offset tracking.

In terms of stability, I've used Flask and Kafka without threads before, and it has worked fine. At least, a producer... My suggestion would be to make a completely separate container for the consumer that's responsible for writing to the database. You don't need the overhead of Flask framework for that. Or, recommended, would be Kafka Connect Mongo sink instead.

The wurstmeister container supports creating topics on its own, via environment variables, by the way.